# DataGridViewColumnSortMode - removing characters appearing in name then sorting alphabetically

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

My code below brings up a list as shown below the code

```
.Columns(0).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
```

The list is fetched from a database so it will be different each time

1. Apples
2. Oranges
3. Pears
4. Cherries

Two things i'd like to do

First - remove numbers and any other characters I choose such as . ) / or anything else i want and then have the list sorted alphabetically so it looks like this

1. Apples
2. Cherries
3. Oranges
4. Pears

Can someone help me achieve this please? I am doing this in VB in Visual Studio.

Comment: What have you tried? Why `Columns(0).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable` ?

Comment: the thing is i am new to this programming

Comment: Use [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e0ywh3cz(v=vs.100).aspx). [This link demonstrates basic data formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f9x2790s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) . [This link describes programmatic sorting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171608(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: thank you...but it tells me nothing on how to get rid of the special characters infront of the names